# PHP asterisk triangle alignment

Tags: php

I'm new to web programming and recently started getting into PHP. I wrote a little code to produce a "right angle triangle". I recognize that using &nbsp is part of the solution but I've placed it in every possible place with no luck so any advice would be appreciated..Below you will find the coding/current output/desired output:

```
$x = 10;
while ( $x >= 1 ) {
    $y=1;
    while ($y <= $x) {
        echo "*";
        ++$y;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    --$x;
}

output:
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*


desire output:
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework ? ;)

Comment: Funny, I just came across the same thing on a course asking us to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 10 characters per line, `n` asterix and `10 - n` spaces. Knowing this, you just need to add another loop inside to control how many spaces to output!

Something as simple as:

```
$x = 10;
while ( $x >= 1 ) {
    $spaces = 1;
    while($spaces <= 10 - $x)
    {
        echo "&nbsp";
        ++$spaces;
    }
    $y=1;
    while ($y <= $x) {
        echo "*";
        ++$y;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    --$x;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it never even crossed my mind to add one more while loop!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion; without `while`s, but using a `for` loop (and `str_repeat()`s).

```
echo '<pre>'; // just here for display formatting

// $x = current number of *
// $t = total number of positions
for( $x = $t = 10; $x > 0; $x-- )
{
    // repeat '&nbsp;' $t - $x times
    // repeat '*' $x times
    // append '<br>'
    echo str_repeat( '&nbsp;', $t - $x ) . str_repeat( '*', $x ) . '<br>';
}
```

And *with* a `while` loop:

```
echo '<pre>'; // just here for display formatting

$x = $t = 10;
while( $x > 0 )
{
    echo str_repeat( '&nbsp;', $t - $x ) . str_repeat( '*', $x ) . '<br>';
    --$x;
}
```

To `echo` your original triangle, just switch the `str_repeat()`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$num = 10;
$char = '*';
$string = str_repeat($char, $num);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
{
    printf("%{$num}s\n", $string);
    $string = substr_replace($string, '', -1);
}

?>
```

Wrap in `<pre>` tags if you want easy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

### I hope this code may be helpfull for you

> new code to create
>   star triangle using `call_user_func()` and `for loop()`

***Star triangle***

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

***Php code***

```
<?php
/**
  | Code for display star triangle using for loop 
  | date : 2016-june-10
  | @uther : Aman kumar
  */

$sum = "*";
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    call_user_func(function($sum) { echo $sum, "<br/>"; }, str_repeat($sum,$i));
}
?>
```